How to catch customer error message in tkinter.Tcl().eval()
I need to use Python to create a simple tcl parser, so I use tkinter.Tcl to do this.
My python interp is 3.9.15
The parsing works well, but when I want to implement behavior for a parsing failure, I find that I can't retrieve the information contained in the TclError that I threw.
Here is my parser code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tcl

def default_command_func(*args):
    print(f'default_command_func : {args}')
    return 'success'

class TclParser(object):
    def __init__(self, data_cls) -> None:
        self.interp = tk.Tcl()
        self.data_cls = data_cls
        self.commands = {}
    
    def register_tcl_command(self, command_name, command_func):
        self.commands[command_name] = command_func
    
    def register_tcl_command_impl(self, command_name, command_func, data_base):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return command_func(data_base, args)
        
        self.interp.createcommand(command_name, wrapper)
        
    def parse_tcl(self, tcl_path):
        with open(tcl_path, 'r') as file:
            tcl_file = file.read()
        data_base = self.data_cls()
        for command_name, command_func in self.commands.items():
            self.register_tcl_command_impl(command_name, command_func, data_base)
                
        try:
            self.interp.eval(tcl_file)
        except tk.TclError as e:
            print(f'unknow error : {str(e)}')
        
        return data_base
    

Here is how i parse my tcl file:
def wrapped_cmd(data_base, args):
    if "error" in args:
        raise tk.TclError("Custom error: Invalid arguments passed")
    else:
        print(f"Executing custom command with args: {args}")
        return "success"


tcl_script = """
custom_cmd arg1 arg2
custom_error error
"""

with open("test.tcl", "w") as f:
    f.write(tcl_script)

parser = TclParser(int)
parser.register_tcl_command('custom_cmd', wrapped_cmd)
parser.register_tcl_command('custom_error', wrapped_cmd)
tech = parser.parse_tcl("test.tcl")

Then I get message like this:
Executing custom command with args: ('arg1', 'arg2')
parse tcl failed due to: 
unknow error : 

My expected output is as follows:
Executing custom command with args: ('arg1', 'arg2')
parse tcl failed due to: Custom error: Invalid arguments passed
unknow error : Custom error: Invalid arguments passed


There's quite a few bits and pieces in there. Did you try printing out the error message before parsing it, just to check to see if it is what you expect?

Before I throw error in wrapped_cmd(), I print error and get correct error message, that's also why I'm very puzzled.

Additionally, I have found that even if I raise a regular error, a tk.TclError is still caught within parse_tcl(), which makes me wonder if there have been any conversions made to the error within the tcl parser.

The error is raised outside the Tcl interpreter, so the Tcl interpreter does not know the excepton message.  Need to raise exception inside the interpreter using parser.interp.call("error", "Custom error: Invalid arguments passed") instead.

Reading through this again, the thing to check is how the Python exception is converted into a Tcl error; if that goes wrong, the failure might look like what you describe. You need to use catch on the Tcl side to trap the failure there and convert it into something that won't cause an explosion when it comes back into Python...
